# Simulación de cientos de dispositivos Android

Tags: android

Como la pregunta dice, necesito simular cientos de dipositivos android. El fin de esto es poner a prueba una aplicación distribuida para poder ver el máximo rendimiento de dicha aplicación.

Las especificaciones de la aplicación, en un principio, son:

- Android 4.1
- Envío de tramas críticas mediante **TCP**
- Envío de tramas no críticas mediante **UDP** cada 20 segundos (geolocalización)

Comment: Mirate deviceFarm de amazon https://aws.amazon.com/es/device-farm/

Comment: podes usar firebase test lab para probarlo en todos los dispositivos